# How do I convert a data.table into a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

I have a data.table that is the result of the summation of 17 matrices. However I need to convert the data.table into a matrix.

This is the code I used to make the data.table:

```
countphij <- rbindlist(lapply(list(all.crossings,count.mat969798,
                              count.mat979899,
                              count.mat989900,
                              count.mat990001,
                              count.mat000102,
                              count.mat010203,
                              count.mat020304,
                              count.mat030405,
                              count.mat040506,
                              count.mat050607,
                              count.mat060708,
                              count.mat070809,
                              count.mat080910,
                              count.mat091011,
                              count.mat101112,
                              count.mat111213,
                              count.mat121314), function(x) setDT(as.data.frame(x), 
        keep.rownames = TRUE)), fill = TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = rn]
```

resulting in the following table:

```
          rn Aa A Baa Ba   B Caa
  1:     A-A  1 4   4  6   2   1
  2:    A-Aa  1 1   0  2   0   0
  3:     A-B  0 1   0  2   3   0
  4:    A-Ba  0 1   4 11   8   1
  5:   A-Baa  1 3  11  4   6   0
  6:   A-Caa  0 1   0  0   3   1
  7:    Aa-A  1 6   1  0   0   0
  8:   Aa-Aa  1 0   1  0   1   0
  9:    Aa-B  0 0   0  3   2   0
 10:   Aa-Ba  0 0   1  6   1   1
 11:  Aa-Baa  0 2   1  4   1   0
 12:  Aa-Caa  0 0   0  0   0   1
 13:     B-A  0 2   2  4   0   3
 14:    B-Aa  0 1   1  3   2   0
 15:     B-B  2 3  19 45 181 117
 16:    B-Ba  0 5  13 42  56  32
 17:   B-Baa  0 0  16  5  20   5
 18:   B-Caa  3 3   8 29  91 149
 19:    Ba-A  1 2   7  5   1   0
 20:   Ba-Aa  0 1   1  0   1   0
 21:    Ba-B  0 1  10 38  60  38
 22:   Ba-Ba  1 4  29 49  39  17
 23:  Ba-Baa  1 7  17 20  20   7
 24:  Ba-Caa  0 2   5 11  27  39
 25:   Baa-A  1 6   7  7   1   0
 26:  Baa-Aa  0 2   0  2   1   0
 27:   Baa-B  3 2   5 21  17  17
 28:  Baa-Ba  1 4  19 18  13  10
 29: Baa-Baa  1 8  32 25  13   6
 30: Baa-Caa  0 0   1  6   9   6
 31:   Caa-A  0 1   1  3   2   1
 32:  Caa-Aa  1 0   1  1   0   1
 33:   Caa-B  2 5  14 38 105 107
 34:  Caa-Ba  1 1   6 22  25  22
 35: Caa-Baa  1 1   4  5   5   3
 36: Caa-Caa  1 2   5 33 149 362
          rn Aa A Baa Ba   B Caa
```

The values in column "rn" in the data.table need to be the row names of my matrix and the columns "Aa" to "Caa" should be by column names for my matrix.

The desired output is:

```
          Aa A Baa Ba   B Caa
      A-A  1 4   4  6   2   1
     A-Aa  1 1   0  2   0   0
      A-B  0 1   0  2   3   0
     A-Ba  0 1   4 11   8   1
    A-Baa  1 3  11  4   6   0
    A-Caa  0 1   0  0   3   1
     Aa-A  1 6   1  0   0   0
    Aa-Aa  1 0   1  0   1   0
     Aa-B  0 0   0  3   2   0
    Aa-Ba  0 0   1  6   1   1
   Aa-Baa  0 2   1  4   1   0
   Aa-Caa  0 0   0  0   0   1
      B-A  0 2   2  4   0   3
     B-Aa  0 1   1  3   2   0
      B-B  2 3  19 45 181 117
     B-Ba  0 5  13 42  56  32
    B-Baa  0 0  16  5  20   5
    B-Caa  3 3   8 29  91 149
     Ba-A  1 2   7  5   1   0
    Ba-Aa  0 1   1  0   1   0
     Ba-B  0 1  10 38  60  38
    Ba-Ba  1 4  29 49  39  17
   Ba-Baa  1 7  17 20  20   7
   Ba-Caa  0 2   5 11  27  39
    Baa-A  1 6   7  7   1   0
   Baa-Aa  0 2   0  2   1   0
    Baa-B  3 2   5 21  17  17
   Baa-Ba  1 4  19 18  13  10
  Baa-Baa  1 8  32 25  13   6
  Baa-Caa  0 0   1  6   9   6
    Caa-A  0 1   1  3   2   1
   Caa-Aa  1 0   1  1   0   1
    Caa-B  2 5  14 38 105 107
   Caa-Ba  1 1   6 22  25  22
  Caa-Baa  1 1   4  5   5   3
  Caa-Caa  1 2   5 33 149 362
```

How could I go about this?

Comment: YOu can convert to data.frame, remove the first column, convert it to `matrix` and set the rownames with first column i.e. `out <- as.matrix(countphij[,-1, with = FALSE]); row.names(out) <- countphij[[1]]`

Comment: `\`rownames<-\`(as.matrix(countphij[,-1]), countphij[[1]])`

Comment: @r2evans very well!

Answer (score 2):

We convert it to `matrix` after removing the first column and set the row names as the first column

```
out <- as.matrix(countphij[,-1, with = FALSE])
row.names(out) <- countphij[[1]]
```

Comment: I found `with=`, but I cannot see the difference it invokes in this context (since no variable names are used). Is it to safeguard against something else?

Comment: In older versions of `data.table`, `dt[, -1]` would return `-1`

Comment: @r2evans  It is just to make it compatible with older versions.  In production scenario, i don't want to take any risks when the version in server is different than the one you are using

Comment: Ahhh, I see the underlying glitch (seems sensible on one level), thanks to both @RyanD and akrun.